# Programmatic android rating bar draws incorrectly

Tags: android, xml, ratingbar

I'm trying to create a rating bar programmatically.

If I use XML everything works perfectly

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/derp">


<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

And the result is a normal, perfectly functional rating bar with red stars ( my accent color).

But if I try and do it programmatically with this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    l.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(getApplicationContext());

    ratingBar.setMax(5);
    ratingBar.setStepSize(1);
    ratingBar.setNumStars(0);

    l.addView(ratingBar);
    ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.derp)).addView(l);
}
```

The result is completely different. The background of the unselected star is invisible, therefore it looks like this.

[Prog emprty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQv9u.png)

The rating bar is there, if you start interacting with it it displays correctly as such

[Prog interacting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VUsr.png)

and as soon as I remove my finger it gets back to an invisible unselected star, but the star that I've selected remain correctly highlighted.

Also the star color is different than the xml one. The rating bar context constructor uses what seems to be the default style though.
This has stared happening all of a sudden in my main app and I can't really figure out why.
I tried to create an empty test app and the problem persist.

Does anybody know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `applicationContext` should usually not be used to inflate a View because your view would then be inflated with the system's Theme, not the theme defined in your application.

Try using your activity context.

```
 RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(MainActivity.this);
```

To learn more about the different `context`'s capabilities there is a [very good article written by Dave Smith](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)